# Programmatically update bash_profile exports

Tags: mac, .bash-profile

I have a program which generates some temporary security tokens in a file. I then have to manually copy the tokens from this file and paste it in my bash profile to proceed further.Tokens expire every 30 mins, so I have to regenerate them and do the manual step of updating bash_profile every 30 mins.

I want to know weather if it is possible to programmatically update and reload .bash_profile from mac terminal when some other system file changes.

For example, I can run this command in Terminal, and it will append a line to my .bash_profile:

```
echo 'export Token=abc' >>~/.bash_profile
```

How can I update the value of Token from **abc** to **xyz** in my terminal?

NOTE: This NOT a code/script request, just looking for some direction and ideas to save time in my daily workflow.

Comment: Provide some dummy examples.

Comment: As a long-time site user, you've probably seen the canned comment that Super User isn't a free script writing service.  So I won't say that.  :-)  But that would be one of the reasons for the question attracting close votes.  Can you tweak the question to provide more specifics, make it sound less like a script request, and maybe include as far as you've gotten with your own code?

Comment: sure, let me clarify that its NOT a script request, I want to know weather if it is possible to programmatically update and reload .bash_profile when some other system file changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing this directly in `.bash_profile` (or `.bashrc` or any similar file) would require managing the *relevant* part of the file while leaving *other* parts intact. This problem has a simple generic solution:

1. Do not change `.bash_profile` over and over again.
2. Create like `~/.my_tokens` which you would change, append to, possibly rewrite entirely.
3. Source the new file from `.bash_profile`. This is the only (and one-time) change you do directly in `.bash_profile`:

   ```
   . ~/.my_tokens
   ```

It's now up to you how you manage the new file. If the file contains just few tokens, the easiest way to update may be to *overwrite* it entirely.

And in case of changes it may be enough to source only `.my_tokens` again, not the whole `.bash_profile`.

You can gather many such files in a directory and source them all:

```
# ~/my_extensions is a directory with no subdirectories
for f in ~/my_extensions/*; do
   . "$f"
done
```

The general idea is to separate "dynamic" tokens from your semi-static `.bash_profile`.

---

The idea of updating these tokens in every *existing* Bash session every 30 minutes or so seems inelegant at least. Consider reading them on-demand (not via `.bash_profile` at all). Let's say `foo` is some external command that needs these tokens. Create a wrapper function:

```
foo() ( . ~/my_tokens; command foo "$@" )
```

Now if you call `foo`, the function will load *current* tokens and call the real `foo` utility. Note the entire function body is in a subshell, so the tokens are not available to the current shell (unless you have separately sourced the file). To source the tokens in the current shell instead, define the function like this:

```
foo() { . ~/my_tokens; command foo "$@"; }
```

Note: for global tokens you should use some path outside any user's directory; example for Linux: `/run/foo_tokens`.

---

An atomic update of `~/my_tokens` (or `/run/foo_tokens` or any other file) can be done with `mv`. You create a temporary file *on the same filesystem*, fill it with data, then overwrite the old version in one final step:

```
mv ~/temp_tokens ~/my_tokens
```

This guarantees any access to `~/my_tokens` gets either the old version or the new one in its entirety. If you updated the file in place, it would be possible to read it as incomplete or partially updated; you certainly don't want this.

Comment: I like the approach of using a separate my_tokens file, and using foo function on demand.

Comment: Can you direct me to an example on how to read a file and overwrite a bash file? Meaning if I have `export Token=abc` in `my_tokens` file, I want to extract a new token `xyz` from another file and update my_tokens file to `export Token=xyz`

Comment: @Himalay Your comment looks like a separate question. The original one is broad enough, let's not make it broader. My suggestion is: do the research (`sed`?) and maybe ask a separate question; if there is no such question already, that is. Make it specific and show your research effort. How many variables are we talking about? For three variables the easiest way is to handle three *separate* files. In such case you already have all the pieces (writing to a new file like in the question, updating the old file atomically, sourcing many files with `for`).